# How to open 2 browsers via same step definition file in Cucumber. Can anyone please suggest

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cross-browser

Please share if anyone knows the solution.
Trying to instantiate 2 browsers with single step definition file

```
@Given("^user is already on Login Page$")
public void user_already_on_login_page(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/naveenkhunteta/Downloads/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com/index.html");
}
```

Comment: create 2 driver instances.

Comment: Why do you need two browser windows? What does having multiple browser windows accomplish? It is very confusing because your step is phrased in the singular sense --- the single user is on the single login page.

Comment: In order to perform crossbrowser testing

Comment: What are you using to execute the tests? JUnit? Testing?